# Why JSON.parse not working on this string?

Tags: javascript, json

This is an object :-

```
var query = {id : "1"};
```

I encoded it : `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(query))`
and got result : `"%7B%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D"`

I decoded it and store in lets say dquery..
`var dqeury = decodeURIComponent("%7B%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D")`

when i print `JSON.parse(dqeury) // it worked, here dqeury = "{"id":"1"}"`

but the same thing when i done on node api, `JSON.parse` will throw an error. when i console the dquery there i get exactly same as before.

How should i parse this??

Comment: What kind of error did you got?

Comment: Please share a minimal code example. The following works for me in node: `var query = {id : "1"};
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(query));
var decoded = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(encoded));
console.log(decoded);`

Comment: I was checking on node , and there i tried with console. it was giving syntax error.